# Stack Exchange API with curl command

Tags: stackexchange-api

By following this [Stack Exchange API documentation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs), I have registered my application on Stack Apps ([here)](https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth/register). After registering I got my `request key` and `access_tokens` created via authentication.

**I need to run the Stack Exchange API via curl command, for that, I ran the following command**

```
curl "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/43919322?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow&access_token=my-access-token)EuzzA((&key=5RseNTJmS0C35DTMsc2dYQ((" | gunzip
```

After hitting the above request, I get the following error :

```
{"error_id":403,"error_message":"`key` is not valid for passed `access_token`, token not found.","error_name":"access_denied"}
```

For authentication, I referred [this](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication) and hit the URL `https://stackoverflow.com/oauth/dialog` with query string parameters, but here also no response is shown.

**Can anyone please tell me why this error is coming, even though the parameters mentioned in the curl request are correct OR is there any step left for authentication?**

Comment: I think that your curl command is correct. About this, you can test by `curl "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/43919322?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow" | gunzip`. From your error message, I think that the key is correct and the access token is not correct. So can you confirm your access token again? From your question, it seems that you use the implicit OAuth 2.0 flow. In this case, this thread might be useful. https://stackapps.com/a/6679/44311 If this was not the direct solution, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike thanks for the reply. The curl command is working fine, but when authentication parameters are included, it shows up the error as mentioned in the question. The thread, which you mentioned above, following that I made the changes in the app, but still I am getting the same error as mentioned above I the question.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. I think that the reason of your issue is your access token. In my environment, I could confirm that the access token retrieved with both explicit and implicit OAuth 2.0 flows worked. So can you provide the values of `scope` and `redirect_uri` of `https://stackoverflow.com/oauth/dialog?client_id=###&scope=###&redirect_uri=###` for retrieving the access token using the implicit OAuth 2.0 flow? By this, I would like to confirm whether I can replicate your situation.

Comment: @Tanaike The parameters are mentioned in this URL -> https://stackoverflow.com/oauth/dialog?client_id=18159&scope=no_expiry&redirect_uri=stackexchange.com . Can you please go through this. Client_id = 18159, OAuth Domain= stackexchange.com

Comment: Thank you for replying. If you are using `https://stackoverflow.com/oauth/dialog?client_id=###&scope=no_expiry&redirect_uri=stackexchange.com`, I think that please modify `redirect_uri` from `stackexchange.com` to `http://localhost`. And, access it. By this, when you see the URL of the browser, you can see `http://localhost/#access_token=###`. In this case, `###` is the access token. How about this?

Comment: @Tanaike for modifying redirect_uri from ```stackexchange.com``` to ```http://localhost```, do I need to make changes in the OAuth Domain (by editing the app)? And, if yes what should I set in OAuth Domain?

Comment: Thank you for replying. In that case, how about setting `localhost` as `OAuth Domain`? Or, if you want to use `stackexchange.com`, please try the URL of `https://stackoverflow.com/oauth/dialog?client_id=###&scope=no_expiry&redirect_uri=http://stackexchange.com`.

Comment: @Tanaike After hitting this URL -> ```https://stackoverflow.com/oauth/dialog?client_id=###&scope=no_expiry&redirect_uri=http://stackexchange.com```, I got access_token. Now are all the authentication steps completed ? And should I hit this ```curl "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/43919322?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow&access_token=my-access-token)EuzzA((&key=5RseNTJmS0C35DTMsc2dYQ((" | gunzip``` with the access token generated .

Comment: Thank you for replying. Yes. When you can see the URL of the browser like `http://localhost/#access_token={accessToken}`, please use `{accessToken}` as the access token. In my environment, I could confirm that the retrieved access token can be used for your curl command. If that was not the direct solution, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike can I use the same curl command as mentioned in the question, with only changing the ```access token``` with the ```new access token``` that I got. Do I have to make the changes in the curl command as I think it is said to use ```GET requests for implicit (client-side) OAuth```

Comment: Thank you for replying. I think that in your case, you can use the curl command for the retrieved access token and the corresponding key.

Comment: @Tanaike thank you so much for replying, I am using the following curl command ```curl "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/43919322?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow&access_token={access-token}EuzzA((&key={key}" | gunzip``` but still same error is coming. Is there something wrong in this curl command ? Or it would be of great help if you can suggest some other curl command through which I can just be sure that the authentication is done correctly .

Comment: Thank you for replying. What is `EuzzA((` of `access_token={access-token}EuzzA((`?

Comment: @Tanaike I am not sure about what ```EuzzA``` is, I have just picked up this curl command from somewhere to test whether authentication is properly configured, it would be of great help if you can just provide a basic format of curl command where I can put ```access_token``` and ```key```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216688/discussion-between-bhavya-and-tanaike).

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your replying. Can you explain about the detail of it?

Comment: @Tanaike thank you so much for your time. I was able to run the curl command with authentication parameters :)

Comment: @Tanaike can you please go through this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62597464/get-all-unaccepted-answers-within-a-date-range-at-user-level-using-stack-exchang

Comment: For your new question, I proposed a workaround for achieving your issue. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike the answer which you gave worked perfectly. Thank you once again :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the discussion done above and the solution given by @Tanaike I was able to resolve the issue.

In order to run the Stack Exchange API with the `curl` command, we need to follow the following steps. To get a detailed explanation refer to this official documentation of [Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs).

**Steps for Authentication**

1. Applications should be registered on [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth/register) to get a request key. Request keys grant more requests per day and are necessary for using `access_tokens` created via [authentication](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication).
2. To register your Application (Click on Stack Apps), write the Application name, Description and in OAuth Domain write `stackexchange.com`.

   Refer to [this answer](https://stackapps.com/a/6679), to get details about registering an application.
3. After registering the application, the client ID, client secret and API key will be generated.
4. Now hit URL `https://stackoverflow.com/oauth/dialog?client_id=###&scope=no_expiry&redirect_uri=http://stackexchange.com` from the browser. This will redirect to `http://stackexchange.com/#access_token=###, where` ###` is the access token.
5. Now run this curl command with authentication parameters

   ```
   curl "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/43919322?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow&access_token=my-access-token&key=my-key" | gunzip
   ```
6. After running the above curl command, the response will be generated.

Comment: @Tanaike I have summarized the above discussion in this answer that helped me resolve the issue. Please have a look at this