# Get the link of question and answer at user level using Stack Exchange API

Tags: json, stackexchange-api

Based on my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62597464/10348758), I am able to get the list of all unaccepted answers within a date range at the user level using Stack Exchange API with the following curl command :

```
curl "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/10348758/answers?page=1&pagesize=100&fromdate=1588291200&todate=1592179200&order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow&access_token=my-access-token&key=my-key" | gunzip | jq '.items[] | select(.is_accepted == false)'
```

The JSON response for the above command is something like this :

```
 {
  "owner": {
    "reputation": 1595,
    "user_id": 10348758,
    "user_type": "registered",
    "profile_image": "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/01ccf806a00d7deb1bf15323bc3edbe8?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1",
    "display_name": "Bhavya",
    "link": "https://stackoverflow.com/users/10348758/bhavya"
  },
  "is_accepted": false,
  "score": 0,
  "last_activity_date": 1592102481,
  "creation_date": 1592102481,
  "answer_id": 62367766,
  "question_id": 62367395,
  "content_license": "CC BY-SA 4.0"
}
```

**In the above response, I am getting `answer_id` and `question_id`, the links to these answers and questions are not included in the response.**

By including `&filter=withbody`, in the curl command I am able to get the body of answer.The modified curl command is :

```
curl "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/10348758/answers?page=1&pagesize=100&fromdate=1588291200&todate=1592179200&order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow&filter=withbody&access_token=my-access-token&key=my-key" | gunzip | jq '.items[] | select(.is_accepted == false)'
```

**Is there any way, I can get the links of the answer and question included in the response? I referred to these custom filters [documentation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/filters), but I am not able to understand how to apply them.**

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this answer?

Your current situation is as follows.

1. The retrieved values from your URL includes both `answer_id` and `question_id`. In this case, the URLs for answer and question can be created like `https://stackoverflow.com/a/{answer_id}` and `https://stackoverflow.com/q/{question_id}`, respectively. I have mentioned at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62597464/get-all-unaccepted-answers-within-a-date-range-at-user-level-using-stack-exchang/62604809?noredirect=1#comment110712277_62604809).
2. In your curl command, `jq` is used like `jq '.items[] | select(.is_accepted == false)'`.

From above situation, in this answer, I would like to propose to add the URLs of answer and question to the retrieved values by adding parameter to `jq`.

#### Modified jq command:

In this case, the modified `jq` command is as follows.

```
jq '[.items[] | select(.is_accepted == false) |= . + {"answerUrl": ("https://stackoverflow.com/a/" + (.answer_id|tostring)), "questionUrl": ("https://stackoverflow.com/q/" + (.question_id|tostring))}]'
```

#### Modified curl command:

When your curl command is modified, it becomes as follows.

```
curl "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/10348758/answers?page=1&pagesize=100&fromdate=1588291200&todate=1592179200&order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow&filter=withbody&access_token=my-access-token&key=my-key" | gunzip | jq '[.items[] | select(.is_accepted == false) |= . + {"answerUrl": ("https://stackoverflow.com/a/" + (.answer_id|tostring)), "questionUrl": ("https://stackoverflow.com/q/" + (.question_id|tostring))}]'
```

#### Result:

When above modified curl command is run, the following result is retrieved. You can see the values of `answerUrl` and `questionUrl` in the result.

```
[
  {
    "owner": {###},
    "is_accepted": false,
    "score": ###,
    "last_activity_date": ###,
    "creation_date": ###,
    "answer_id": ###,
    "question_id": ###,
    "content_license": "###",
    "answerUrl": "https://stackoverflow.com/a/###",  <--- Added
    "questionUrl": "https://stackoverflow.com/q/###"  <--- Added
  },
  ,
  ,
  ,
]
```

#### References:

- [Usage of /answers/{ids}](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers-by-ids)
- [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

### Added:

When you want to include the title to the retrieved values, please use the custom filter as follows.

#### Modified jq command:

```
curl "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/10348758/answers?page=1&pagesize=100&fromdate=1588291200&todate=1592179200&order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow&access_token=my-access-token&key=my-key&filter=%21T%2AhPUiv_%28m%28rgrhfg_" | gunzip | jq '[.items[] | select(.is_accepted == false)]'
```

- In this case, the filter of `filter=%21T%2AhPUiv_%28m%28rgrhfg_` is added as the query parameter. By this, the title is added. In this custom filter, `title,link,.share_link` are included. By this, the title, answer and question links are included in the returned values. So the command of `jq` can be simpler.

#### Reference:

- [Custom Filters](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/filters)

Comment: thank you for your answer! This worked like a charm :), but here is it possible to get the title of the question also included in the question link For example : For this question ```https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62606821/get-the-link-of-question-and-answer-at-user-level-using-stack-exchange-api/62607859#62607859``` The title of the question is included In the URL

Comment: @Bhavya Thank you for replying. I couldn't notice that you wanted to retrieve the title. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this. For retrieving the title, I added one more modified curl command in my answer. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: Thank u for replying. On running the above-modified curl command I am getting this error ```jq: error (at <stdin>:0): Cannot iterate over null (null)```

Comment: @Bhavya Thank you for replying. Using the custom filter, it includes the title, answer and question links. For this, I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: @Bhavya In your curl sample, I forgot that `filter=withbody` was included. By this, such error occurs. So I removed it. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: The modified curl commands run perfectly :) Thank you so much :)